# jQuery equivalent to `return document.getElementById(theVar)'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've a javascript function

```
function $m(theVar){
    return document.getElementById(theVar)
}
```

The problem with the above code is, the element I want to pass is generated by ajax so I need something like the `.live()` in jquery, unless it throws an error

How do I rewrite the above function in jQuery so that any DOM element generated later can also be detected.

Update:

When my page first load, it loads

1) ajaxupload.js with codes

```
function ajaxUpload(form,url_action,msg){
   var id_element= "pop-con";
   function $m(theVar){
        return document.getElementById(theVar)
    }
   if($m(id_element)==null){
        erro += "The element of 3rd parameter does not exists.\n";
    }
}
```

2) index.php with codes

```
<div id="popupMargin">
    <div class="close">x</div>
    <div id="pop-con"></div>
</div>
<div id="ajaxGenerateMarkUp"></div>
```

3) now on the click of a button, the following markUp is added to the `#ajaxGeneratedmarkUp` div (mark-up generated through ajax)

```
<form  onSubmit="return disableForm(this);" action="crop/wizecho_upload.php" method="post" name="f" id="wizecho" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input id="file" type="file" name="file"  onChange="return disableForm(this), ajaxUpload(this.form,'crop/wizecho_upload.php', '&lt;br&gt;Uploading image please wait.....&lt;br&gt;'); return false;"/>
</form>
```

Now on change of this input type file, made the call on in the javascript. Now it shows the error.

[Note: I only posted sections of code I think might affect my question]

Comment: Your function will work fine, as long as the element exists at the time your function is called. In other words, your function is aready like `.live()`. Or maybe you want the function to return a reference to an element that will be created in the future?? I'm not sure I understand the question.

Comment: The function above and the element referring to by `theVar` here is loaded at page load. A button click somewhere in the page generates a `<div>` using ajax with a 2nd button inside it. I click on the second button and call this function but the function returns `null`

Comment: `theVar` should not contain an element. It should be a string. Please post more of your code. But if you use jQuery anyway, then use it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

jQuery's selector can detected newly generated items:

```
$('#id');
```

So in your case:

```
var theVar = 'something';
$('#' + theVar); //returns a jQuery object of the select item
$('#' + theVar)[0]; //returns the first DOM object that jQuery finds with that id
```

Comment: so i write `return $('#' + theVar);` ?? It doesnt seem to work

Comment: give us some more context then, because this does in-fact work. And what I am saying is that you do not need a function, because there is one already built into jQuery.

Comment: your example returns a jQuery object, not a DOM object, so it is not equivalent to `return document.getElementById(theVar)`

Comment: @jessegavin I realize that he said he wanted it rewriten in jQuery, I missed the part where he said he wanted to still use a DOM object. **Edit:** Changed main post to include returning a DOM object as well.

Comment: notice this will fail if `theVar` contain special characters like `.`, which should be escaped in CSS selector. e.g. `$('#a\\.b')[0] === document.getElementById('a.b')`

Answer (score 8):

Like this:

```
return $('#' + theVar)[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add a `live` call somewhere to detect the new AJAX-loaded button. This way, the button will be automatically bound to a handler that works OK as in other answers. From your comment I guess you are doing one of these:

- In the AJAX-loaded button you already include some JS logic, that is not working (something like `onclick="do_something"`).
- You are binding the second button to a handler withoug the `live` method.

Here's a working example. Although it doesn't load contents via AJAX, it does load a dynamic button.

http://jsfiddle.net/marcosfromero/VKfKL/

**Update:** Another example that does load contents via AJAX and binds the newly created button with `live`:

http://jsfiddle.net/marcosfromero/h9RSC/